# Model.save failing?

Tags: ruby, rest, post, sinatra

I'm trying to add a user to a database through the POST method of a Sinatra application. My database connection is working fine - I'm able to GET with `User.all.to_json`. However, when I try to POST, I get a nondescript server error saying that my request failed. From what I can tell, it has to do with the `user.save` call. What am I doing wrong?

```
  post '/users/?' do
    @request_payload = JSON.parse request.body.read

    user = User.new(name: @request_payload["name"],
                    email: @request_payload["email"],
                    created_at: @request_payload["created_at"],
                    last_sign_in_at: @request_payload["last_sign_in_at"])

    user.save
  end
```

Edit: not sure if it's relevant, but here's the schema of the database I'm connected to:

```
Table "public.users"
         Column         |            Type             |                     Modifiers                      
------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id                     | integer                     | not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 email                  | character varying(255)      | not null default ''::character varying
 encrypted_password     | character varying(255)      | not null default ''::character varying
 reset_password_token   | character varying(255)      | 
 reset_password_sent_at | timestamp without time zone | 
 remember_created_at    | timestamp without time zone | 
 sign_in_count          | integer                     | default 0
 current_sign_in_at     | timestamp without time zone | 
 last_sign_in_at        | timestamp without time zone | 
 current_sign_in_ip     | character varying(255)      | 
 last_sign_in_ip        | character varying(255)      | 
 name                   | character varying(255)      | 
 created_at             | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at             | timestamp without time zone | not null
 authentication_token   | character varying(255)      | 
 password_updated_at    | timestamp without time zone | 
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_users_on_email" UNIQUE, btree (email)
    "index_users_on_reset_password_token" UNIQUE, btree (reset_password_token)
```

Comment: Can you post the exact content of the error?

Comment: When i say 'non-descript' i mean it. Here's the error: "There was an error processing your request." And the user.save call is returning false.

Comment: I was hoping it was a syntax or basic structural error that someone with more experience would be able to spot. I don't think it's related to the database connection, since I'm able to GET without any trouble. Also, those column names (name, email, created_at, last_sign_in_at) are the correct column names of the database table.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of quick options:
DataMapper (looks like you're using DataMapper) now supports raise_on_save_failure; you can apply it as
user.raise_on_save_failure
right before your save call, and the console should display all manner of explody goodness.

Or you can dump user.errors.full_messages if save returns false. More on this can be found here.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/d/dm-validations-1.2.0/DataMapper/Validations/ValidationErrors.html

I'm concerned about the fact that you're passing no value to a nullable column that has a unique index on it (the reset token column).

Comment: Big help, thanks. `user.errors.full_messages` gave me a meaningful error I was able to debug.